# Failed to find provider info for cn.teddymobile.free.anteater.den.provider

Tags: android, android-layout

i have a question about this log, what does it mean ? i don't understand, but my bar chart has appeared. My data has not appeared. log :

```
E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for cn.teddymobile.free.anteater.den.provider
```

Android Manifest :

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.cn.teddymobile.free.anteater.den.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true"
    tools:replace="android:authorities">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"
        tools:replace="android:resource" />
```

xml - > path :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Comment: Think that `android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"` would do.

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: Well compare it with what you have now.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when trying to share a pdf file in Android 12 (it worked in Android 10), and solved it by adding `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` flag in the opening intent. Like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by clearing the data on the application.
Just go to Settings -> App Management -> (name of your application) -> Storage Usage -> Clear Data.

Answer (score 0):

just clear the app data of your app you are working on and you should be good to go..

Comment: This answer is same as the one given by @user16652721